# Software that converts Audio to Video

Tags: linux, open-source, video, audio, media-converter

I want to know how to convert an audio file to a video, of either with or without adding images. I know that TEncoder, a great software for Windows does that. But I want something like that for Linux. I know that TunesToTube does this but it's not offline and not suitable for batch conversion.
So my question is clear:

> How to convert audio to video?

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to TEncoder and TunesToTube? Which video formats do you need? Which audio formats need to be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [avconv](https://www.libav.org/index.html) to combine one or more images with an audio track.

- Works Offline
- Cross Platform Linux & Windows
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Command line &/or scriptable
- Huge range of possible input & output formats.

Example of ffmpeg use from the [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest out.mp4
```

Example of avconv use based on the snippets something like:

```
avconv -framerate 25 -f image2 -i image-%03d.jpeg -b 65536k -i audio.wav  -c:a libmp3lame -qscale 20 -shortest out.mov
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It now works great. Also found that movavi and openshot are also capable of it.